# How to add ExcelPackage reference in C#

Tags: c#, nuget

Please help me: how to add reference for `ExcelPackage`?

In the following line

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
```

I'm getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have already called `Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml`

Comment: Are you sure you are installing the package in correct project? Go to the Package Manager Console, make sure that the selected project is correct.

Comment: Actually i coppy the code from website but at ExcelPackage i'm getting Error

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting?!?!?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: added error message

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `Install-Package EPPlus`  for this u need Tool----->Library----->package console

Comment: using OfficeOpenXml;

// to reference EPPlus.

Answer (score 1):

You can install package from "Package Manager condole" like below:
For specific verrsion

```
PM > Install-Package EPPlus -Version 4.5.2.1
```

without version

```
PM > Install-Package EPPlus
```

Generating excel refer blog: http://sforsuresh.in/generating-and-formatting-excelsheet-in-c-using-epplus/

Comment: Do we have to buy this for commercial use?

Comment: @VarunKumar:  Paid and free both versions are available. You need to choose according to your requirement.